# How to Create QGridLayout at run time and generate rows dynamically?

Tags: qt

How to Create QGridLayout at run time and generate rows dynamically and add buttons to it dynamically ?

On button i want to place a Image & label at run time.

I am creating four buttons on button click and try to place a icon on it , but it is not appearing on it and i am trying to make my grid as scrollable(vertically) but it is not getting scrollable.

```
 QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);         

       QPushButton *b1 = new QPushButton(strsearch);
       QPushButton *b2 = new QPushButton(strsearch);
       QPushButton *b3 = new QPushButton(strsearch);
       QPushButton *b4 = new QPushButton(strsearch);


       b1->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 162, 26));
       b2->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 162, 26));
       b3->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 162, 26));
       b4->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 162, 26));
       b1->setIcon(QIcon("user.gif"));
       b1->setIconSize(QSize(160, 26));
       b2->setIcon(QIcon("user.gif"));
       b2->setIconSize(QSize(160, 26));
       b3->setIcon(QIcon("user.gif"));
       b3->setIconSize(QSize(160, 26));
       b4->setIcon(QIcon("user.gif"));
       b4->setIconSize(QSize(160, 26));

       QVBoxLayout *vl = new QVBoxLayout;

       layout = new QGridLayout;  // this is your grid layout
       vl->addWidget(b1);
       vl->addWidget(b2);
       vl->addWidget(b3);
       vl->addWidget(b4);

       vl->addLayout(layout);
      scrollArea->setWidget(vl->widget());
       vl->addWidget(scrollArea);

       setLayout(vl);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing very special about adding things to a layout at runtime.

I'd suggest you create the grid layout and store it as a member of the widget into which you want it displayed, and connect your button's `clicked()` signal to a custom slot if that widget.

Something like this:

```
class Win: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Win(QWidget *parent=0): QWidget(parent)
    {
        QPushButton *b1 = new QPushButton("click");
        QVBoxLayout *vl = new QVBoxLayout;
        layout = new QGridLayout;  // this is your grid layout
        vl->addWidget(b1);
        vl->addLayout(layout);     // added to the widget's main layout
        setLayout(vl);
        connect(b1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(clicked())); // connect button to slot
    }

    public slots:
        void clicked()
        {
            int position = layout->rowCount(); // this works out as the first row index with nothing on it
            QPushButton *b = new QPushButton;
            b->setIcon(<<the icon you want>>);
            b->setText(<<the text you want>>);
            layout->addWidget(b, position, 0);
            layout->addWidget(new QLabel(<<whatever you want here>>), position, 1);
                    ...
        }

    private:
        QGridLayout *layout;
};
```

Nothing prevents you from adding a new `QGridLayout`, and adding new widgets to it, at runtime. It's probably going to be a bit tough managing a variable number of layouts on your UI.

---

Your code does not make much sens. You're adding your buttons to the `QVBoxLayout`, then adding an empty grid layout to it, then setting your scroll area's widget to something that doesn't exist (`vl->widget()` will return NULL, since a QVBoxLayout is not a widget, see [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qlayoutitem.html#widget)), then adding that scroll area into the layout you were trying to include into the scroll area itself?

You need to nest the layouts and widgets properly.

- Add the buttons to the grid layout if that's what you want.
- Then create a container widget for that layout (a `QFrame` for instance), and set that widget's layout to your grid layout.
- Then add that `QFrame` into a `QScrollArea`.
- Then put add scroll area to your container widget's layout.

Please go through the the Qt samples and [layout documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/layout.html), including the [Image Viewer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/widgets-imageviewer.html) sample. You need to study more about layouts.

Comment: @Mat : Thanks.But how to place image and lable on top of button at run time.

Comment: Just create the button and set the icon/text (updated my sample code to show that). There is nothing special about what you are asking, look at the [qt tutorials](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/widgets-tutorial.html), they show you the basics of how to create widgets (at runtime).

Comment: @Mat : 
My requirement is like  i should create buttons based on search result and it should be scrollable also.How to make it scrollable ?

Comment: You include your widget in a scrollable area, or use a widget that's meant for that (i.e. a QTableWidget or QListWidget). You'll need to spend some time & effort researching this yourself, the Qt docs have plenty of samples for you to look at and the class documentation itself is very extensive.

Comment: edited my answer, but please please read the documentation about Qt layouts. The code you posted doesn't really make sens.

Answer (score 1):

As well as statically (:

Before adding new layout you should remove old layout and widgets. After that you need to add new layout and widgets.

And don't forget to call `show` for all widgets and form/dialog where your layout is located.

**UPD:**

```
b1->show();
b2->show();
b3->show();
b4->show();

this->update();
this->show();
```